# How to get the value after the hash in "somepage.php#name"?

Tags: php, url

For a given url, I want to get the name-after-hash's age from the database. so for url like `thepage.php#Madonna`, you'll see "`119!`".

How can I extract the value after the hash in a url? (i need a safe all-browser-compatible-NON-JAVASCRIPT way). I want to do that like $_GET['after hash'].

The reason I'm not using GET is because I want to use AJAX and jquery's history plugin.

Basically what i want is to use ajax to retrieve data from the server according to the value assigned after the hash.

Comment: If NON-JAVASCRIPT, then answer is: It is not possible, browsers doesn't send anything what is after # that is behavior by design.

Comment: Ah, I see the misinterpretation, you mean after the #.
In programming the word "Hash" has a special meaning, it doesn't refer to the # symbol.
I'd call it the #, or the number symbol.

Comment: but I don't want JS to be a requirement for using my website. I want it to work, at least for the user's perspective, the same way when using JS and when not.

Comment: Change your URL scheme to be something like thepage.php/Madonna instead.  That trailing part of the url is accessible by parsing $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]

Comment: @Paul, but then if the url is thepage.php/Madonna I wouldn't be able to use jquery's history plugin. Do you know any way I can manipulate a url with ajax?

Comment: (what i mean is that when a user hits "next" button, ajax will get another value from the db, the url will change to /Obama and display whatever).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.  The string after # is interpreted by the browser as an anchor name within the current page.  It is not passed to the server.

Comment: Definitely a good point -- the URL fragment of the current page isn't available to PHP.  It's unclear if that's relevant to the OP's issue, however.  The fragment *is* available to Javascript.

Comment: Exactly. This can even be used when forging URLs for XXS attacks when you don't want to be detected by server side security components, like IDS.

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript

`window.location.hash` will give you this value. You can then pass it (via AJAX) to the server for results.

## PHP

Check the Fragment of [parse_url();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

**Return Values**

On seriously malformed URLs, parse_url() may return FALSE and emit a E_WARNING. Otherwise an associative array is returned, whose components may be (at least one):

- scheme - e.g. http
- host
- port
- user
- pass
- path
- query - after the question mark ?
- **fragment - after the hashmark #**

Comment: IF browser would be so kind to send fragment to You, but it's tricky.

Comment: Do you know a php function with which I can extract the ENTIRE url to pass in parse_url($url)?

Answer (score 0):

This question didn't make much sense, you need to clarify it.

You want to hash the URL without Javascript, but in a way that can be used by Ajax?

Comment: what?! absolutely not. I want to extract the value AFTER the # in the url.

I don't need to clarify my question buddy, you need to clarify your reading.