# How can i get the page.html#PARAMETERS through PHP?

Tags: php, http

How can I get the value of the URL hash (eg `"PARAMETERS"` in url `"page.html#PARAMETERS"`) on the server in PHP?

Comment: Doesn't anybody SEARCH anymore?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/php-get-value-from-url-after-sign

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value after the hash in "somepage.php#name"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917762/how-to-get-the-value-after-the-hash-in-somepage-phpname)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, at least not directly. The fragment identifier is never sent to the server.

You could extract it in JS using `location.hash` and then trigger another HTTP request to the server that includes it as data (e.g. in the query string).

Answer (score 4):

You can't, unless you got something client-side to explicitly transfer it to you. The fragment part is only handled by the browser.