# Getting FULL URL with #tag

Tags: php

Tried to print the $_SERVER array in PHP, yet I can't find what I want:

http://www.domain.com/#sometaginpage

I want the "sometaginpage".

Help. Thanks!

Comment: `window.location.hash` in JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value after the hash in "somepage.php#name"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917762/how-to-get-the-value-after-the-hash-in-somepage-phpname)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The browser doesn't actually send anything that comes after the hash(#) to the server because it is resolved within the browser.

Comment: It is not resolved via JavaScript at all. It is resolved via an anchor tag <a>.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I was mistaken and have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just ended using Javascript:


var url=window.location.toString();if(url.indexOf("STRING_HERE")!=-1){window.location = ".URL_HERE";}

Answer (score 4):

Fairly certain that `#hashtags` are NOT sent to the server, but you could develop a workaround with AJAX:

**some-page.html**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
            var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
            $.get('ajax-hash.php', { tag: hash },
                function(data) { $('#tag').html(data); }
            );
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="tag"></div>
<a href="#one">#one</a> | <a href="#two">#two</a> | <a href="#lolwut">#lolwut</a>
```

**ajax-hash.php**:

```
<?php
    $hash = isset($_GET['tag']) ? $_GET['tag'] : 'none';
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '#' . $hash;
?>
```

**Note:** This is dependent on the browser actually sending the `HTTP_REFERER`.. Since it's done through jQuery, it SHOULD.. but no promises! (Antivirus/Firewalls love to strip that from your packets)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will give it or not. s992 might be right, it may not send that to the server.