# Get URL with JQuery like http://url.com/#!page1

Tags: php, url

My problem is that I use a JQuery plugin which allows me to slide between pages (which are actually divs in an html page). And each of my "pages" have an address like that:

```
http://url.com/#!page1
http://url.com/#!page2
http://url.com/#!page3
```

How can I get the #!page part?

I hope my explanations were clear.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: [hashbangs are evil](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs), fix the plugin to use `pushState` and friends instead.

Comment: The answer has been deleted but thanks to the guy who posted it, I got what I wanted!
I asked for a way to get it in PHP, but I realized that it was better for me to get it via JQuery and window.location.hash is a perfect solution!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I couldn't understand fully what OP was asking.

The hashtag part is handled only by the browser (by `window.location.hash`). If you really need to get it, here is a suggestion:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6119468/867418

**This is for manipulating already defined URLs.**

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/function.parse-url.php) function.

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Result:

```
Array (
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor ) /path
```

Comment: Presumably the question is asking about the URL the browser is requesting, not one in a string embedded in the program.

Comment: Thanks! window.location.hash is what I was looking for!
It's better for me to get it with JQuery rather than in PhP.
Thanks for the answer!