# document.write not returning string

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i want to get the string after # tag in url with php. but there is no function to find it. so i get it by the javascript on the same page and call that variable into php by

```
  <script>
  var query = location.href.split('#');
  var a =  String(query[1]);
  </script>          

  <?php 
     $variable = "<script>document.write(a)</script>"; 
     print_r (explode("%",$variable));
  ?>
```

but this code print the string as it is and it doesn't split by %.

gives the result like 
`Array ( [0] => z%a )` for this link  http://immersed.in/CodeIgniter/#z%a

please help what to do

Comment: You're looking for `explode('#', $url);`

Comment: @Daan but it's not actually explode the url. if i check with storing manual static link then it explodes but if i run above code.. it gives whole string as it is

Answer (score 0):

*"but this code prints the string as it is and it doesn't split by %.?"*

```
<?php 
     $variable = "<script>document.write(a)</script>"; 
     print_r (explode("%",$variable));
 ?>
```

Yes the compiler (interpreter) is right!, because when you say `$variable = "<script>document.write(a)</script>";` the variable `$variable` is a string variable because you have `<script></script>` does not mean that it will be execute as js script for two reasons:

1. Your script is under quote
2. Even though you put it out of quote it wont work because you are on the server side ( on php code..) it will not execute till your code comes to the client side ( browser)

Also trying this wont work:
    explode('#', $url);

because url part after the # is not sent to the server. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119095/getting-full-url-with-tag)

Also it might be helpful to read about client side vs server side langs.

Comment: is there any php function to get whole URL.. i didn't find any so use javascript to get hashtag value

Comment: Undefined variable: url. what php function to get url ? so i can use it to store in $url

Comment: oh you have to define the `$url` variable here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Comment: but any of php function will not return url after # tag. is there any?

Comment: use the link I gave you to get the url and then use the function on the answer (explode)

Comment: sorry to asking help again. but i write this http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
and it don't send me the value after # tag.
also there is  a comment
"This function does not include username:password from a full URL or the fragment (hash)."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get hash tag using php. And javascript will run on client side and php will run on server side. Refer to this links. Similar answer : [Getting FULL URL with #tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119095/getting-full-url-with-tag),

Comment: yes.. that i know and that's why i use javascript to get hash value and store in to php as above mentioned code.. but question is how can i explode php variable?