# I need to extract exact url using php including the id in the address

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, extract, window.location

I need to extract following url using php : "http://www.website.com/profile#username". All the methods that I have tried return "http://www.website.com/profile"

Comment: what is the final string that u want???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting FULL URL with #tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119095/getting-full-url-with-tag)

Answer (score 2):

Just use parse_url()

```
$url = 'http://www.website.com/profile#username';
$parse = parse_url($url);
print $parse['host']; // prints 'website.com'
```