# PHP get anchor attribute

Tags: php, url, get, anchor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the value after the hash in “somepage.php#name”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917762/how-to-get-the-value-after-the-hash-in-somepage-phpname)

Is it possible to get an anchor name with PHP?

For example, for this URL:

```
http://domain.com/#departments
```

How can I get the text "departments"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to get things after "#" in php, because this data is not provided to server, only url without data after "#", but if you are executing php script through JavaScript, you can Always split url into "#" and send the data as parameter or value of some hidden field.

Comment: "executing php script through JavaScript"? You very nearly got a +1 until I read that. Still, you're right that, if the source of the request -- be it a Javascript invoking XmlHttpRequest, or be it a human being -- reforms the URL then it will be easier to work with in this regard. Aw, hell, have the +1.

Comment: lol good one, I thought to write if you are executing AJAX request to server or XmlHttpRequest or ... in other browsers, then I thought if this can be the problem then he probably wont understand it so I have written JavaScript :)

Comment: and with executing I thought about sending request to server using JavaScript hahah lol me

Comment: That would have been less vague, yes.