# How to parse non querystring parameters?

Tags: php

I am experimenting with the [Discord API](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#implicit-grant-authorization-url-example) which doesn't return querystring parameters and I can't use `parse_url()`.

The URL looks like this: `httpS://example.com/discord/#token_type=Bearer&access_token=TOKEN&expires_in=604800&scope=identify`

Notice the `#`.

I would like to access the `access_token`, could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: When you say _"I can't use `parse_url()`"_, is that because there is no query string in the URL or is it for some other reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)

Comment: @Phil Yes, there is no query string in the URL.

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032242/how-to-obtain-anchor-part-of-url-after-in-php) are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917762/how-to-get-the-value-after-the-hash-in-somepage-phpname) duplicates [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby) this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967649/get-entire-url-including-query-string-and-anchor/967659). It can be hard to come up with the right search terms, but please do try searching before posting a new question.